# How does one differentiate from question writers and trolls?

Tags: discussion

If a question provokes a large no of viewers to comment it gets upvoted or downvoted more often. Isn't this similar to trolling? Pardon me if I have hurt any feelings.

Comment: raising controversial questions isn't trolling.

Answer (score 5):

Trolling can be described as intentionally provoking negative feelings and reactions based on them. Provoking thoughts, debates, and similar is something different.

Sure, some people pose questions just to troll, but that’s only a small portion.